# jQuery json php json not working

Tags: jquery, json

In php i created an array named :

```
$errorsa = array();
```

Then for each error i add it something values in array by something like this :

```
$errorsa[] = array("id"=>"rules","error"=>"You need to agree to rules");
```

Then at the end of the file i do this :

```
echo json_encode($errorsa);
```

Then in my main file i do something like this :

```
$("#submiter").click(function() {
    $.post("submit.php",
        $("#formmain").serialize(),
        function(data) {
            $.each(data,function() {
                $("#result").append(this.error);
            });
        },
        "json"
    )
});
```

But this aint working ?
I am new to json and looking forward on it.
What have i dont wrong in this ?

Comment: Have you tried displaying the response data to see if it is actually an object?

Comment: @logan U mean on the php side ? or does it returns any value ?

Comment: try adding same sys.out in both sides PHP and JS. so you can see where is the problem!

Comment: @kritya - What happens when you open submit.php in your browser.  I expect you're cueing off of form fields, but can you just add query params (you'd be using the $_REQUEST object) or are you explictly using $_POST?  Alternatively, you can use a packet sniffer (necessary for AJAX, IMO), or the Net panel of Webkit's Inspect/Firebug.

Fact is, I've looked through this several times and I don't see any problems with the code that is here.

Comment: @john Well before this i was using a submit button so it returned perfectly fine.
I recieve the value of it just like this $_POST['main'] ?

Comment: If it was just a swap between submit buttons, the issue sounds like a problem in serializing the form data.  Again, packet sniffers would tell us much more... what is actually going over the wire to the PHP and what it is spitting back out.  Fiddler is a must have on the PC, I use HTTPScoop on the Mac (and you can use the Inspect/Firebug panels I mention earlier).

Comment: @arthur What and how ?!?

Comment: @john What do i do correct it ?

Comment: You don't know what the problem is yet, so that isn't a question anyone can answer.

Comment: @john There should be some error for sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this:

php:

```
<?php
$errorsa = array();
$errorsa[] = array("id"=>"rules","error"=>"You need to agree to rules");
echo json_encode($errorsa);
?>
```

JS:

```
$("#submiter").click(function() {
        $.post("submit.php", function(data) { $.each(data,function(){alert(this.error)}) },'json')
    });
```

Comment: Isnt this just same as mine except the alert thing .. ?

Comment: pretty much! but I just test it, and is working!! try: http://arthurnn.com/test.html

Comment: @kritya also! try using the alert just to see what your php function is returning back for you!

Comment: Ill try in maybe an hour or two :D

Comment: what was the output of your alert?!

Comment: what could be happening is your submit.php page is returning an error(500 or 404) !! try going directly to your php page, for example in my case: http://arthurnn.com/submit.php  and see the return!( if it is a actual JSON file)

Comment: I know i checked that it returns a big list of json as i want. There

Comment: @kritya let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2331/discussion-between-arthur-neves-and-kritya)